# Dreamweaver says my stylesheet is not on the local disk?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

So, I'm a beginner in HTML and I'm trying to use CSS, but Dreamweaver says that my stylesheet is not on the local disk, which I don't understand since my whole directory for this site is saved on my desktop. So my site has currently no design and I have no idea how to repair that. I tried some small things I saw on the internet like changing my directory name for something different from the file but it did not work...

The error message is : **'stylesheet.css' is not on the local disk. GET**

Here is the start of my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheet.css">
</head>
```

The stat of my CSS file:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Here's some screen shots of what have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jDsG.png)

Comment: My uneducated guess is that `../stylesheet.css` is not where you think it is reletive to the html. Where is the HTML file located, and is there a build process that moves the files around?

Comment: Your CSS path is wrong, try this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Css/stylesheet.css">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah this cause, your CSS path is wrong. According to screen shot, It looks like your `stylesheet.css` file in under `css` directory.

So you can change

`href="../stylesheet.css"`

into

`href="css/stylesheet.css"`

**Note**: I guess, your `index.html` file should be under the parent directory, `site`, the same directory that has the `css` folder.

Comment: would that not be `.../css/stylesheet.css` ?

Comment: No, because I think `index.html` will be under `site` directory. I also mentioned that as note in my answer.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I'm just dumb af :') Thanks a lot tho, it'll help me be more careful about it from now on!

Comment: @Hassaan I double checked the screenshot and you're right, by bad.

Comment: @AsrealM. this happens in beginning. Best of luck. Accept my  answer if you found it helpful